# published bot on skype but it's not working

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a bot that I've created by merging **LUIS** and **QnA** together in a single project using Microsoft Bot Builder.
I published the bot to an EC2 instance from visual studio and I'm using the Bot Framework Emulator for testing and it works perfectly. (MUST use ngrok for tunneling).

Now I want to deploy the bot on Skype. I logged into the Bot Framework Portal and I registered my bot. Now comes the configuration part.
I'm not quite sure what to set as the HTTP endpoint here.

I found this in the Bot Framework documentation:

> **Complete the Configuration section of the form.**
>
> Provide your bot's **HTTPS** messaging endpoint. This is the endpoint
>   where your bot will receive HTTP POST messages from Bot Connector. If
>   you built your bot by using the Bot Builder SDK, the endpoint should
>   end with */api/messages*.
>
> - If you have already deployed your bot to the cloud, specify the endpoint generated from that deployment.
> - If you have not yet deployed your bot to the cloud, leave the endpoint blank for now. You will return to the Bot Framework Portal
>     later and specify the endpoint after you've deployed your bot.

When I published from Visual Studio, from the Azure App Service Activity windows, I found this line:

> Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://ec2-00-000-000-00.compute-1.amazonaws.com:PORT/msdeploy.axd?site=bots ...

I used that address for the Messaging Endpoint in the configuration and I published my app. However when I'm testing it on Skype, i'm not receiving any messages from the bot.

I don't know what the problem is exactly, does this have something to do with ngrok? Or am I missing a step here, is there something else I should be doing to deploy the bot on Skype? Maybe something to do with the appid/password that I need to use ... i really don't know

Would really appreciate an explanation of how this works exactly. I don't really understand how the whole deployment procedure works exactly, feels like i'm swimming in murky waters.

Comment: Where did you deploy the bot?!

Comment: @OmG bot is deployed to an EC2 Instance that I have setup and running it on a Skype channel.

Comment: Does your server have a valid SSL certificate?

Comment: @NilsW WoW! how did you catch that?
That was the problem. I didn't have a valid SSL. It's fixed now, and communicate with the bot just fine. thank you so much

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint is going to be the root of your deployed web application instance, plus the route that your bot is listening on.

For example, one of my bots is deployed to the free version of Azure Web Sites. The URL for a site such as this is `https://APPLICATION_NAME.azurewebsites.net` and the route that the bot listens on is the default `/api/messages`. This makes the endpoint `https://APPLICATION_NAME.azurewebsites.net/api/messages`.

If you connect directly to your app's endpoint, you should at least get a JSON dump with an error message. To make sure your site is getting deployed, drop an HTML file into the root of EC2 and see if you can access this.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.